# Why isn't SQLAlchemy translating this object generated by a FactoryBoy SubFactory into a foreign key?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, factory-boy

I'm using Flask and SQLAlchemy (via the Flask-SQLAlchemy extension) together with [Factory_Boy](https://github.com/rbarrois/factory_boy).

My `GearItem` model has a foreign key to `GearCategory`. [Factory_Boy](https://github.com/rbarrois/factory_boy) handles this through the `SubFactory` function that creates the object to be used as the foreign key in the original factory.

Here are my model definitions:

```
class GearCategory(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    gear_items = db.relationship('GearItem', backref='category',
            lazy='dynamic', order_by='GearItem.name')

class GearItem(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False, index=True)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('gear_category.id'), index=True)
```

And here are my factory_boy `Factory` definitions:

```
class GearCategoryFactory(BaseFactory): # Based on factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory
    class Meta:
        model = gear_models.GearCategory
    name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda n: faker.word())

class GearItemFactory(BaseFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = gear_models.GearItem
    name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda n: faker.word())
    category_id = factory.SubFactory(GearCategoryFactory)
```

I can call `GearItemFactory()` with no problems and it's clearly generating both a `GearItem` and a parent `GearCategory` that's intended to be used as the foreign key.

However, when I call `db.session.flush()`, SQLAlchemy doesn't translate the object created by the `SubFactory` into an integer that can be used as the foreign key. Instead, it tries to pass the object itself to the underlying database driver, which then complains that has no idea how to handle an object of type `GearCategory`.

The error that I'm getting is `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (db_driver) can't adapt type 'GearCategory' [SQL: 'INSERT INTO gear_item (...`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to show how you are actually creating the objects here.  But also I don't know what factory boy is and it appears to be some major element here, so perhaps email them for support.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the `GearItemFactory` definition specifies a Python object reference for the foreign key database ID. `sqlalchemy` has no problem translating Python objects into database Foreign Key ID. However in my factory I specified an object-to-database column mapping rather than an object-to-object mapping, so SQLAlchemy (rightfully) thinks I want to pass the Python object straight to the database. Just need to change the factory foreign key to an object-to-object mapping and `sqlalchemy` will handle the actual database FK column behind the scenes.

This is the broken line:

```
category_id = factory.SubFactory(GearCategoryFactory)
```

See how the `backref` on `GearCategory` is named `category` not `category_id`?
Updating that line to use `category` fixes the problem:

```
category = factory.SubFactory(GearCategoryFactory)
```