# factory-boy subfactory passes object instead of key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, factory-boy

I am using factory boy with SQLAlchemy.

I am trying to create Fact objects, and I want factory boy to generate PatientDim objects that are foreign keys to Fact. But Subfactory doesn't pass the key, instead it passes the entire object to the foreignkey field.

How can I only pass the PatientDim key thru Subfactory?

Factories.py

```
class FactFactory(SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Fact
        sqlalchemy_session = common.Session

    patient_id = factory.SubFactory(PatientDimFactory)

class PatientDimFactory(SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.PatientDim
        sqlalchemy_session = common.Session
```

Models.py

```
class Fact(TimeStampedModel):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'fact'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    patient_id = Column('patient_id', Integer, ForeignKey(PatientDim.__table__.c.id), nullable=False)
    patient = relationship(PatientDim, foreign_keys='Fact.patient_id' )

Base = declarative_base()
class PatientDim(TimestampMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'patient_dim'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: One year later, no answer.  Got this figured out?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like the same issue I found in this question: [Why isn't SQLAlchemy translating this object generated by a FactoryBoy SubFactory into a foreign key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31872497/13847277)
Based on that, the issue is this names the SubFactory based on the `patient_id` column and not the relationship `patient`.

In the examples here: https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/blob/master/examples/flask_alchemy/demoapp_factories.py you can see they name the SubFactory based on the relationship, not the column for the foreign key. So it looks like updating that to `patient = factory.SubFactory(PatientDimFactory)` should work.

Comment: Thank you, that linked question is useful. It does matter what name is specified in `backref=`  of the `relationship`.

Answer (score 2):

### My today's workaround:

Generate dict data from Factory

```
import factory
data = factory.build(dict, FACTORY_CLASS=FactFactory)
```

Create ForeignKey/subFactory object

```
patient_dim = PatientDimFactory()
```

Change the foreignKey object in created data

```
data['patient_id '] = patient_dim.pk
```

Use crated data in a create Form

```
form = MyCrateForm(data=data)
```

Comment: Would be good if you add explicit 'import factory\n ... \n' in first example, at first I didn't realize that 'factory' was a module name, not a variable referring to some factory.